# Insert values for whole column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to insert **different** values for specific column, not whole row in SQL Server.
Classic UPDATE SET would set all to same value.

[image]

For example I want to set some int values to Ranking column for each of 3 rows, without dropping them and doing complete new insert into.

Comment: You mean an `UPDATE`?

Comment: @Larnu Kind of, but update would usually set all to same value, what if you need different values?

Comment: `insert into [table] (name, Ranking) values(Neutral, 10)`

Comment: Use a `JOIN`? A `CASE` expression? Depends on your goal. an `UPDATE` doesn't set the same **value** for every row in a column, it uses the same **expression**. That expression can evaluate to a different value for every row. For example, the statement `UPDATE YourTable SET Ranking = ID * 2;` would generate a different value for every row, provided that `ID` is unique (which I ***assume*** it is).

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`

```
  update a set ranking =rn from tablename a join 
    (select id,name, row_number() over(order by id) as rn
        from tablename) b on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

do update

```
update tabale 
  set ranking= your_va

   with cte as
   (
    select * ,row_number() over(order by id) rn
   ) update cte set ranking=rn where id<=3
```

Answer (score 0):

What value do you want to set `ranking` to?

Just any value:

```
update mytable set ranking = id;
```

Certain values:

```
update mytable set ranking =
  case name 
    when 'Positive' then 1
    when 'Neutral'  then 2
    when 'Negative' then 3
                    else 4
  end;
```